# Snowflake - convert timestamp to date serial number

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL table containing timestamps of the following format:

`2022-02-07 12:57:45.000`

In SQL Server, you can convert this to a floating point date serial number (days since 1900-01-01):

```sql
select convert(float, my_timestamp_field) as float_serial_number
```

which yields an output of:

| float_serial_number |
| --- |
| 44597.5401041667 |

I am trying to get the same output in Snowflake, but cant figure out how to return a float. This is as close as I have gotten:

```sql
select 
datediff(day, '1900-01-01', '2022-02-07 12:57:45.000') as integer_only,
timestampdiff(day, '1900-01-01', '2022-02-07 12:57:45.000') as same_as_above
```

which yields an output of:

| integer_only | same_as_above |
| --- | --- |
| 44,597 | 44,597 |

The output I need in Snowflake (this takes the time into account where 12pm = 0.5):

| desired_Snowflake_output |
| --- |
| 44597.5401041667 |

Answer (score 4):

You could calculate the diff in decimals using either these- (seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds) in `datediff` and dividing that by the appropriate denominator

```
set mydate='2022-02-07 12:57:45.000'::timestamp;

select datediff(seconds, '1900-01-01', $mydate)::float/86400
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an sql function that does the job

```sql
create or replace function dayfloat_ts(ts TIMESTAMP)
returns float
language sql
as
$$
    (datediff(day, '1900-01-01', TS)::float +
    (datediff(nanoseconds, '1900-01-01', TS)::float -
    datediff(nanoseconds, '1900-01-01', date_trunc(day, TS)))::float / 86400000000000::float)
$$;
```